# MUS cores in Alloy UNSAT models

Tags: smt, alloy, sat, mathsat

I am working on a software that uses Alloy Tools library to find MUS(Minimal Unsatisfiable Subset) of alloy models that are unsatisfiable (UNSAT), for my tests I have 2 models one that only has Facts and another with only Predicates, at this moment the software works correctly but I have been stuck because I have not been able to find more Alloy models (.als files) that are UNSAT and that when removing the MUS they become SAT, I need at least 200 to make a performance test, is there any place where I can find these for Alloy the ones I have found are for SAT-Solvers like MinSAT and other not for Alloy.

Try some pages but those only offers models for other SAT-Solvers

Comment: There can be multiple unsat cores within the same formula. Have you tried removing more than once?